# Error changing a file's access control at install time

Tags: c#, file-io, wix

I´m trying to change a file´s access control at install time. More, specifically, through a Wix´s Custom Action, so I am sure that it is being executed with admin rights.

Here´s the code:

```
   string pathVersioningDat = ConfigurationManager.GetPath("versioning.dat", true);
   FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
   FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(pathVersioningDat);
   fSecurity.SetAccessRule(rule);
   File.SetAccessControl(pathVersioningDat, fSecurity);
```

I know it works in several computers. It doesn´t work in any W7 Starter Editions and neither, in some few cases, in other Windows 7 Editions.

The exception message (IdentityNotMappedException) is "Some or all identity references could not be translated". Seems like "everyone" user cannot be found in these computers, but I'm not sure. It occurs at System.Security.Principal.NTAAccount.Translate method.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue came to our development team time ago.

You have not specified the language of your Windows 7 Starter Edition. We realized that in many machines with Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate Edition this problem never happened, but with Starter Edition in English neither. However, we could see certain problems when using other languages (Spanish, for instance).

Have you tried installing Windows 7 Starter in English from scratch? (Notice that Windows 7 Starter does not allow you to change the language once installed).

**EDITED:**

If you wanted to avoid this problem in the future you could use this solution:

```
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
string pathVersioningDat = ConfigurationManager.GetPath("versioning.dat", true);
FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(pathVersioningDat);
fSecurity.SetAccessRule(rule);
File.SetAccessControl(pathVersioningDat, fSecurity);
```

With the [WellKnownSidType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype.aspx).WorldSid value you don't have to worry about initial languages in your target operating systems.

Tell me if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

[antiocol seems to be right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13086068/572834).

On Russian versions of Windows, *Everyone* is called *Все*. This is not limited to Starter versions. All the built-in accounts and groups are localized. Even if you later change the language to English (in Ultimate editions), the names of the built-in accounts remain in Russian.

I'd advise using built-in, or [Well-known SIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), directly. For *Everyone*, use `SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY` and `SECURITY_WORLD_RID`.

<sub>I cannot give you code sample on how to use it C# though.</sub>